# How do I deserialize XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

I have several xml files with the same structure, and I would like to have all data in one List. A list of players.

Each xml contains thousands of players.

Unfortunatly, I have only the first player of each xml file.
Where is my error and how to correct it ?

Thanks for your answers.

my xml file has these structure (full structure below, in my model) :

```
<playerslist>
<player>
<name>John Doe</name>
<country>ENG</country>
<rating>1850</rating>
</player>
<player>
<name>Johnny Depp</name>
<country>USA</country>
<rating>1765</rating>
</player>
<playerslist>
```

My C# code :

```
if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolderPath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolderPath);
                var allStandardFiles = dirSource.GetFiles("*standard*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

                List<Playerslist> listAllEntriesStandard = new List<Playerslist>();


                foreach (var nextFile in allStandardFiles)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Playerslist));
                        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(nextFile.FullName)))
                        {
                            Playerslist result = (Playerslist)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                            listAllEntriesStandard.Add(result);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

and my model :

```
public class PlayerXML
{
    public class Player
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "fideid", Namespace = "")]
        public int FideId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Namespace = "")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "country", Namespace = "")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sex", Namespace = "")]
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title", Namespace = "")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "w_title", Namespace = "")]
        public string W_Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "o_title", Namespace = "")]
        public string O_Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "foa_title", Namespace = "")]
        public string Foa_Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "rating", Namespace = "")]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "games", Namespace = "")]
        public int Games { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "k", Namespace = "")]
        public int K_Factor { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "birthday", Namespace = "")]
        public int Birthday { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "flag", Namespace = "")]
        public string Flag { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "playerslist", Namespace = "")]
    public class Playerslist
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "player", Namespace = "")]
        public Player Player { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Player Player { get; set; }` needs to be an array or list of `Player`s.

Comment: Have a look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Serializer
{
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string deserializedObject)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var reader = new StringReader(deserializedObject.Replace("&#x0;", "").Replace("encoding =\"utf-16\"", ""));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public static string SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, obj); 
        return sw.ToString();
    }

}
```

You should import System.IO and System.Xml.Serialization

And this my objects

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyAnotherObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MyObj Obj { get; set; }
}
```

And I use

```
var myObj = new MyAnotherObj();

//Set myObj

var serializeObj = Serializer.SerializeObject(myObj);
var deserializeObj = Serializer.DeserializeObject<MyAnotherObj>(serializeObj);
```